# How to compel the browser to get the webpages from a server not from a local cache even if a particular page is frequently requested?

Tags: html, browsers, cache, cache-control

I have been testing a web site but every time I complain to the web developer that I am not able to see on the website which you have recently corrected,he told me that I am seeing that content from the browser cache. I should press F5 and get the recently corrected contents of the webpage.

Can I fix something (1) at a web page source code level or (2) at browser level so the browser gets the recent page i.e. from server only not from its cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

between your `<head>` tags, this should force the browser to not cache anything in *most* browsers.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing for you is to **bypass your cache**.

This is usually done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

There are some variances by browser and you can check on this and see how to **completely clear the cache** at [this Wikipedia page on 'Bypass your cache'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache).

If you opt to completely clear your cache after changes are made to the site this will probably work best for you as successive page loads will use the newly cached page (featuring the most recent changes to the site). That way you see the changes and keep getting the performance benefits of browser cache.